# Debug Flutter Web in new tab in existing browser instance

Tags: dart, flutter-web, vscode-debugger

I would like to find a way to debug a Flutter Web app from vscode in a new tab in my existing browser instance. By default, vscode also always opens a brand new browser instance regardless of an already open browser instance. My vscode launch configuration looks like this:

```
        {
            "name": "Flutter Web Project",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "-d",
                "chrome"
            ]
        }
```

I have tried `attach` instead of `launch` without success.